# Any input on why the .DataApi.addListener(... , this) only seem to get called by the Mobile app and not the Wear app?

Tags: java, android, google-data-api, android-wear-data-api

.onConnected() never seems to be reached by my [[Wear - MainActivity]](https://github.com/michaeldvinci/WristaRoo_Android/blob/master/wear/src/main/java/com/michaeldvinci/conedmiro/schedaroo/MainActivity.java) regardless of how it gets called.

I can see the S.O.P. for the .onConnected() for the [[Mobile - MainActivity]](https://github.com/michaeldvinci/WristaRoo_Android/blob/master/mobile/src/main/java/com/michaeldvinci/conedmiro/schedaroo/MainActivity.java) as well as the S.O.P. where:

```
DataMap map = putDataMapReq.getDataMap();
map.putStringArrayList(WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH, actsList);
System.out.println("[mobile] - StringArray /hopefully/ put");
map.putLong(TIME_MESSAGE_PATH, System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println("[mobile] - Timestamp /hopefully/ put");
```

gets called, but when I try running:

```
System.out.println(putDataReq);
```

I get a reply with:

```
PutDataRequest[dataSz=247, numAssets=0, uri=wear:/wristaroo, syncDeadline=1800000]
```

So am I not adding a listener to my mGoogleApiClient correctly --? I tried implementing a WearableListenerService [which is shown on my GitHub] but I don't know how to add it to mGoogleApiClient and then get the corresponding data form the Message....

Any input would be greatly appreciated....